# show two cam on mobile using getUserMedia API

Tags: mobile, getusermedia

tested on desktop with no issues, but on mobile we can have just one stream at the same time, means we can not have two stream one from front cam and the other from back cam

```
 let frontCam = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: { facingMode: "user" },
    audio: true
  });
 // the second stream will not success if we are on mobile
 let backCam = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: { facingMode: "environment" },
    audio: true
  });
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sad but true.  One `.getUserMedia()` camera stream at a time is all the most mobile devices support.